# Which type of Tizen project should I use?

Tags: tizen

I have studied the Tizen office document for a while, I have a chat app to develop at Tizen platform, the app  include follow functions :
  Normal socket communication ,reading local contact , scaning qr code, record media,using WebRtc library. In other words , hope it like WhatsApp .Which one to choose between html+js and c + xml? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

- Normal socket communication

  - webapp : can use websocket but it is not normal socket.
  - native : just use the normal socket.
- Reading local contact

  - webapp : can [contact](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4.0/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/mobile/tizen/contact.html) web device API
  - native : can use [contacts](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CAPI__SOCIAL__CONTACTS__SVC__MODULE.html) device API
- scaning qr code

  - webapp : no api but there are many js lib is exist for it. [ref it.](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/articles/barcode-generator-and-scanner?langredirect=1)
  - native : can use [media vision barcode](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=/dev-guide/latest/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CAPI__MEDIA__VISION__BARCODE__MODULE.html&langredirect=1) device API
- record media

  - webapp : can use [media capture](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)
  - native : can use [audio input](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CAPI__MEDIA__AUDIO__IN__MODULE.html) and [recorder](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CAPI__MEDIA__RECORDER__MODULE.html) api
- using WebRTC library

  - webapp : can use [getUserMedia](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4.0/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/w3c_api/w3c_api_m.html#media) but not support webrtc until 3.0
  - native : can use many native webrtc libraries. but does not have in device api.

It looks almost same difficulty at features you want.
personally I think native should more easier than web app at support webrtc.

You can pick native or webapp that you feel a little bit more easier.

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer  that  every function have a related link .[link] (https://developer.tizen.org/forums/general-support/which-one-choose-between-native-and-web?langswitch=en) the link have related answer